# Where is the implementation of the function lh_OBJ_NAME_retrieve in OpenSSL 1.1.1k

Tags: c, openssl

I'm reading the source code of OpenSSL 1.1.1k, the code I'm currently reading was downloaded from the [1.1.1k release page on github](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/releases/tag/OpenSSL_1_1_1k).

I've just found something strange by trying to figure out the implementation of `EVP_get_cipherbyname`.

---

The function `EVP_get_cipherbyname` calls `OBJ_NAME_get` and returns what `OBJ_NAME_get` returns as the `EVP_CIPHER` object it needs to return:

```c
/* crypto/evp/names.c line 58 */

const EVP_CIPHER *EVP_get_cipherbyname(const char *name)
{
    const EVP_CIPHER *cp;

    if (!OPENSSL_init_crypto(OPENSSL_INIT_ADD_ALL_CIPHERS, NULL))
        return NULL;

    cp = (const EVP_CIPHER *)OBJ_NAME_get(name, OBJ_NAME_TYPE_CIPHER_METH);
    return cp; 
}
```

And then, in function `OBJ_NAME_get`, it calls a function named as `lh_OBJ_NAME_retrieve` and returns the `data` field of the structure which returned by the function `lh_OBJ_NAME_retrieve`, and that should be the actual `EVP_CIPHER` object we get from `EVP_get_cipherbyname`:

```c
/* crypto/objects/o_names.c line 172 */

const char *OBJ_NAME_get(const char *name, int type)
{
    OBJ_NAME on, *ret;
    int num = 0, alias;
    const char *value = NULL;

    if (name == NULL)
        return NULL;
    if (!OBJ_NAME_init())
        return NULL;
    CRYPTO_THREAD_read_lock(obj_lock);

    alias = type & OBJ_NAME_ALIAS;
    type &= ~OBJ_NAME_ALIAS;

    on.name = name;
    on.type = type;

    for (;;) {
        ret = lh_OBJ_NAME_retrieve(names_lh, &on);
        if (ret == NULL)
            break;
        if ((ret->alias) && !alias) {
            if (++num > 10) 
                break;
            on.name = ret->data;
        } else {
            value = ret->data;
            break;
        }
    }   

    CRYPTO_THREAD_unlock(obj_lock);
    return value;
}
```

But the problem is, the keyword `lh_OBJ_NAME_retrieve` only appears at this very single place, there is no actual implementation can be found in OpenSSL-1.1.1k, I just searched the whole project by running `grep -ri lh_OBJ_NAME_retrieve` in the root directory of the project and grep only finds one entry which is the one inside function `OBJ_NAME_get`.

Google does find me something about this mysterious function, in older version of OpenSSL like 1.0.1, this function can be found in `crypto/stack/safestack.h` as an alias of `LHM_lh_retrieve`, but in 1.1.1, it's nolonger there, it just nolonger exists.

So where is the function `lh_OBJ_NAME_retrieve` implemented in OpenSSL 1.1.1.

Comment: Maybe try building with `--save-temps=obj` and then grep the `.i` and/or `.s` files?

Comment: @o11c YES! I find it, by building OpenSSL with --save-temps, the keyword lh_OBJ_NAME_retrieve appears in crypto/objects/o_names.i and it's an alias of OPENSSL_LH_retrieve.  Thanks a lot!